# coffeescript pass arguments to returned function

Tags: coffeescript, method-chaining

I'm not sure if there's a JavaScript-term for what I'm trying to accomplish in CoffeeScript, but here's the use-case:

I'm loading JS modules with CommonJS, and they might load objects, functions, anything.
If I loaded an object literal, for example, I can access its properties **in-line**, chained after the require() call.

```js
// car.js returns an object properties and methods
var make = require('car').make
```

This is possible in CoffeeScript as well since they introduced method chaining:

```coffee
make = require 'car'
  .make
```

But...

In JS, if the `require()`'d file returns a function, I can call it in-line:

```js
// drive.js 
module.exports = function(distance, speed) {
  return distance / speed;
}

// index.js
var hours = require('drive')(1200, 120); // 10
```

The following attempts cause an error:

```coffee
// drive.coffee
module.exports = (distance, speed) ->
  distance / speed

// index.coffee
hours = require 'drive' 1200, 120           // error unexpected number
hours = require 'drive'
  1200, 120                                 // error unexpected indentation
hours = require 'drive' (1200, 120)         // error unexpected (
```

How can I do this is CoffeeScript?

Comment: You still can do `hours = require('drive')(1200, 120)`

Comment: Seriously, one of the claims of coffeescript is improved readability. How is `require 'drive' 1200, 120` more readable than `require('drive')(1200, 120)`? (It isn't, and fortunately it's also wrong.)

Comment: first, this is in part an exercise to understand CS syntax better. secondly, I do believe that `require 'drive' (1200, 120)`, for example, is pretty readable and intuitive

Comment: But why would you expect `f x (y)` to be `f(x)(y)` rather than `f(x(y))`? Or do you expect CoffeeScript to behave specially if it knows that it is working with a string literal?

Comment: i wouldn't expect that - which is why i'm wondering if there's another form of special syntax for these on-the-fly callbacks, like the new method-chaining syntax

Answer (score 1):

the answer is brackets.

```
// drive.coffee
module.exports = (distance, speed) ->
  distance / speed

// index.coffee
driveFunction = require('drive')
hours = driveFunction(1200, 120)
```

or shorter

```
hours = require('drive')(1200, 120)
```

Comment: well, this is pretty much JavaScript syntax... I'm trying to understand if there's some sort of CS syntax that can compile to this.